# "injected" css background not rendered in Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, background, background-image

I got the Twitter-Timeline widget and in order to further customize its CSS I use jQuery to overwrite some of the widget's CSS rules, like so:

```
function customizeTwitterFeed() {
    $($("iframe").contents()).find("#twitter-widget-0").css({ background: "transparent" });    

    var hentryCss = {
        background: "url('img/bap/hLine_small.png') scroll no-repeat center bottom",
        border: "none",
        color: "#cccccc",
        fontSize: "16px"
    };

    var hentryACss = {
        color: "#5c7f9d",
        textDecoration: "none"
    };

    var timelineHeaderCss = {
        background: "url('img/bap/twitterIcon.png') scroll no-repeat 8px center, transparent",
        paddingLeft: "48px",
        color: "#668995",
        fontSize: "28px"
    };

    $($("iframe").contents()).find(".h-entry").css(hentryCss);
    $($("iframe").contents()).find(".h-entry a").css(hentryACss);
    $($("iframe").contents()).find(".timeline-header").css(timelineHeaderCss);
}
```

While the background-styles defined in the variables `hentryCss` and `timelineHeaderCss` seem to render fine in Firefox, they are not displayed and apparently not even loaded in Google Chrome. I opened the element inspector in Chrome and saw that the respective elements had `background: url()` applied.
I suspect a possible solution would be to use `!important` with my background-CSS but I don't know how to send that parameter with jQuery's css() method - appending it inside the background-property's value string only results in a css-error.
I use the background-shorthand for other elements as well (though in my own stylesheet) and for those elements it's working fine in both browsers.

Tested in Firefox 28 and Chrome 34.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: I noticed the iframe, so this is probably a cross-domain issue. You are not supposed to alter the content of a foreign iframe. Firfox is probably the one that is wrong here, not chrome.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed answer - my internet connection was down for a few days:
hm yes, that makes sense - but how is one supposed to modify the widget's CSS then? To be frank, the options in the Twitter configurator are a joke...

Comment: Put your code in JSFiddle, please.